# IPL match between two groups using arrays

Tags: java, arrays

It would be great, if someone could help me out using two dimensional array concept, rather than using collections.
Because i have to use arrays in this logic and get the output.

Problem:

Group 1 has four teams named ('A','B','C','D')
Group 2 has four teams named ('E','F','G','H')

User has to select two teams to play (one from group 1 and another from group 2).

Condition 1: (logic written below and working fine)
But the team from the same group shouldn't play (For eg: 'A' and 'B' team shouldn't play).

Condition 2: (logic written below and working fine)
Teams from different group can play (For eg: 'A' and 'E' team can play).

Condition 3: (please help me on this logic)
Teams from different group cannot play more than 2 times. 
(For eg: 'A' and 'E' team can play only twice).
Third time we are not supposed to allow them to play.

Program:

```
package demo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Ipl {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String[] teamOne = new String[] {"A","B","C","D"};
        String[] teamTwo = new String[] {"E","F","G","H"};
        boolean flagA = false;
        boolean flagB = false;
        String teamA = null;
        String teamB = null;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        for(int l=0; l< 5 ;l++) {

            System.out.println("*******IPL MATCH 2019**********");
            System.out.println("Group A");
            for(String a: teamOne ){
                System.out.println(a);
            }
            System.out.println("Select one team from group A ");
            teamA = br.readLine();


            System.out.println("Group B");
            for(String b: teamTwo ){
                System.out.println(b);
            }
            System.out.println("Select one team from group B ");
            teamB = br.readLine();


            flagA = contains(teamOne,teamA);
            flagB = contains(teamTwo,teamB);

            if( flagA && flagB ){

                for(int i=0 ; i < teamOne.length ; i++){
                    if(teamOne[i] != null){
                        if((teamOne[i].equals(teamA)) && (teamOne[i].equals(teamB))){
                            throw new Exception("Both the team belongs to the same group");
                        }

                    }
                }

                for(int k=0 ; k < teamTwo.length ; k++){
                    if(teamTwo[k] != null){
                        if((teamTwo[k].equals(teamA)) && (teamTwo[k].equals(teamB))){
                            throw new Exception("Both the team belongs to the same group");
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Both Team belongs to the different groups, hence they can play");

            } else {
                System.out.println("Please select teams from the availability");
            }

        } 
    }

    private static boolean contains(String[] teams, String team) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean flag = false;
        for(String select : teams) {
            if( select.equals(team)){
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package demo;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Ipl {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String[] teamOne = new String[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
        String[] teamTwo = new String[] { "E", "F", "G", "H" };
        String[] fixtures = new String[10];
        int fixtureCount = 0;
        boolean flagA = false;
        boolean flagB = false;
        String teamA = null;
        String teamB = null;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        for (int l = 0; l < 5; l++) {

            System.out.println("*******IPL MATCH 2019**********");
            System.out.println("Group A");
            for (String a : teamOne) {
                System.out.println(a);
            }
            System.out.println("Select one team from group A ");
            teamA = br.readLine();

            System.out.println("Group B");
            for (String b : teamTwo) {
                System.out.println(b);
            }
            System.out.println("Select one team from group B ");
            teamB = br.readLine();

            flagA = contains(teamOne, teamA);
            flagB = contains(teamTwo, teamB);

            if (flagA && flagB) {
                for (int i = 0; i < teamOne.length; i++) {
                    if (teamOne[i] != null) {
                        if ((teamOne[i].equals(teamA)) && (teamOne[i].equals(teamB))) {
                            throw new Exception("Both the team belongs to the same group");
                        }

                    }
                }

                for (int k = 0; k < teamTwo.length; k++) {
                    if (teamTwo[k] != null) {
                        if ((teamTwo[k].equals(teamA)) && (teamTwo[k].equals(teamB))) {
                            throw new Exception("Both the team belongs to the same group");
                        }
                    }
                }

                int matches=0;
                for (int j=0; j<fixtureCount; j++) {
                    if( fixtures[j].equalsIgnoreCase(teamA+":"+teamB)){
                        matches++;
                    }
                } 
                if(matches == 2){
                    System.out.println("Already two matches fixed for the same team, please select a different combination");
                }
                else{
                    fixtures[fixtureCount++]= teamA+":"+teamB;
                    System.out.println("Both Team belongs to the different groups, hence they can play");
                }                                                              
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please select teams from the availability");
            }
            System.out.println("Available fixtures :");
            for (int j=0; j<fixtureCount; j++) {
                System.out.println(fixtures[j].replace(":", " vs "));
            } 
        }
    }

    private static boolean contains(String[] teams, String team) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean flag = false;
        for (String select : teams) {
            if (select.equals(team)) {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        return flag;
    }

}
```